# Why is my method not found?

Tags: objective-c

I have a custom init method for my `SecondViewController : UIViewController`

```
-(id) initWithFirstViewController:(FirstViewController *)theFirstViewController
{
    self = [super init];

    fvc = theFirstViewController;     

    return self;   
}
```

So in my `FirstViewController` I call this init method with an instance of the `FirstViewController` as a parameter. Somewhere else in the `SecondViewController` I use this passed intance:

```
[fvc setSomething];
```

The method is executed but I get a warning:

> Method `-setSomething` not found (return type defaults to `id`)

How to fix this?

Comment: Please quote the complete error message (it says to which type of object the method call was sent). Also, does FirstViewController actually have the `setSomething` method ?

Comment: It says "Semantic Issue" and displays exactly the warning that I posted in my question, the method exists and is executed

Comment: So that's a compile time error rather than a runtime error ? Back to my question, does `FirstViewController` actually implement the method ? And do you have you importet the corresponding `.h` file where it is defined ?

Comment: thanks, the last thing with the import helped, FirstViewController wasn't imported, can you add this to your answer plz. However I removed the import some time ago because I had some trouble with recursive imports...

Comment: Have edited the answer. Have a nice day !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, it's a matter of `#import`ing the corresponding `.h` file so the compiler knows about the method.

Additionally, you should retain `theFirstViewController` as chances are that it gets released and a different object is created at exactly the same memory location (to which `fvc` is still pointing). So you should do `fvc = [theFirstViewController retain];` as you are "holding on to" the first view controller (you want to make use of it later on). Don't forget to release it in your `dealloc`.